# Custom spacing for MUI Grid component

Tags: material-ui

In Material-ui grid, we can pass `spacing` as a prop to specify the spacing between grid items but this assigns equal padding on all sides.

Is there a way to specify a different padding for top-down and a different padding (or maybe no padding) for left-right?